# Split string on commas but ignore commas within double-quotes using shell scripting in a .csv file?

Tags: shell, csv, awk, sed

**Sample 'null.csv' file contains**

> 71131940,2015-05-01,"JEWELLERY,ITEM",P,,W

I have a .csv file in which I want to handle commas(,) and null values(,,) so that when I split each line of the file using (,) it ignores commas within double-quotes and does not give the output like this given below.

> 71131940,2015-05-01,JEWELLERY,ITEM,P,,W

I handled null values i.e (,,) by replaces it with (,0,) using sed command

> sed -i -e "s/,,/,0,/g" null.csv

and got output something like

```
71131940,2015-05-01,JEWELLERY,ITEM,P,0,W
```

But the problem is that, in here I don't want to split "JEWELLERY,ITEM" into
JEWELLERY,ITEM .

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: CSV parsing is a pain if you need to follow all the rules around quoting and escaping. If you can use python for your solution, it gets easier. e.g. `python -c 'import csv;print "\n".join(list("\t".join(row) for row in list(csv.reader(open("null.csv")))))'`

Comment: Eric thanks for your quick reply but I am looking for shell script which lets me do so.

Comment: I always wondered who comes up with requirements such as "edit CSV, JSON, or XML with shell scripts".  But anyway, [this](https://github.com/dbro/csvquote) little program can help you fulfill your dream, if adding it to the picture isn't against requirements, that is.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Thank you so much. It did help me a ton! Wasn't even expecting to see a solution like that and was breaking my head for hours for the exact reasons stated in the readme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure this has been asked and answered a million times but in any case, for input formatted as simply as you have shown (e.g. no quoted quotes or newlines within quotes):

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print i, $i}' file
1 71131940
2 2015-05-01
3 "JEWELLERY,ITEM"
4 P
5
6 W
```

The above uses GNU awk for `FPAT` (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content).